# What's the point of the SSCALED AND USCALED format types in OpenGL AND Vulkan?

Tags: opengl, vulkan

With SSCALED and USCALED if you read integer values the shader will sampled and return that integer value converted directly as a float, so integer 255 becomes 255.f, not 1 like UNORM would do, or 255 as an integer as an integer sampler would do. My question is given you can just sample with an integer sampler and then assign that value to a float, why does this format exist?

Answer (score 3):

> you can just sample with an integer sampler

This requires changing the shader. Or more accurately, binding an entirely new pipeline object that has a different shader that uses an integer sampler instead of a floating-point one.

Or you can keep the shader the same and just bind a different descriptor.

It should also be noted that formats don't have to be supported by an implementation for images. Vertex formats use the same formats as images. And far more implementations [support vertex buffer usage](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listbufferformats.php) than [support image format usage](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listoptimaltilingformats.php)

Comment: Vertex buffer basically means as input attributes, right? And the other two mean texelFetch?